# I have a problem when using a package from R in Python with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm new in Python and I could really use some help! I'm trying to use a package from R in Python. I installed the package as follows:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3'
os.environ['Path'] += r';C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin\x64;'
from rpy2 import robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
packnames = ('DMwR')
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames))
DMwR = importr('DMwR')
```

This is how I installed the library. Now, I want to use it but I don't know how. Take a look:

```
datos1 = robjects.r[DMwR.CentralImputation(datos1)]
print(datos1)
```

If someone could help me, I would be really thankful.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has an introduction that should help you get started. That introduction has an example showing how to call R functions in packages imported with `importr()`:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/introduction.html#linear-models